# Optimize intersection of large sets

Tags: python, optimization

The premise is simple: I have two integers, `a` and `b` and I want to find `i` s.t. `a + i` and `b + i` are both in a given list. The list `rs` is very large (10e9 items). I have the following code:

```
def getlist(a,b):
    a1 = set([i - a for i in rs if i>a])
    b1 = set([i-b for i in rs if i>b]) 

    tomp = list(a1.intersection(b1))
    return tomp
```

The issue at hand is that a1 and b1 are pre-computed first which creates a memory problem. Can I optimize my code somehow? General comments about the method are also welcome.

Example input:

```
rs = [4,9,16]
a = 3
b = 8
```

Expected output:

```
getlist(3,8) = [1]
```

Comment: Does this gives the expected output?

Comment: yes, as long as len(rs) <=10e6

Comment: I guess you don't need to create two sets, you could try: `tomp = [i - b for i in rs if i - b in a1]`

Comment: How would you do it without 2 sets?

Comment: How about `a1 = set([i - a for i in rs if i>a])`
    `b1 = set([i-b for i in a1 if i>b])`

Comment: In the ends I believe this boils down to finding all pairs that add up to a given sum, there very efficient ways of finding that. Including one with `O(n)` complexity. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720271/find-a-pair-of-elements-from-an-array-whose-sum-equals-a-given-number

Comment: @Daniel It's not exactly that, the sum is not a given one but can rather be one in the large array. But performance wise I already see an improvement with the optimized snippet.

Comment: Could you add some sample input (small) together with the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `rs` is already a `set`, this would be faster:

```
def getlist(a, b):
    return [i - a for i in rs if i > a and b + (i - a) in rs]
```

If it is not, then you have to make the set first (otherwise the above algorithm would be very slow) and the performance is essentially the same as before:

```
def getlist(a, b):
    rs_set = set(rs)
    return [i - a for i in rs_set if i > a and b + (i - a) in rs_set]
```

However, if you are going to use the same function many times for different `a` and `b` values but the same `rs`, you can convert `rs` to a set once and reuse it every time.

Comment: This is in fact at least 2.5x faster than any other answer, even accounting for the conversion to set().

Answer (score 4):

You can optimize the memory usage by skipping the creation of the second set (and intermediate lists):

```
def getlist(a, b):
    a1 = {i - a for i in rs if i > a}
    return [i - b for i in rs if i > b and i - b in a1]
```

The time and space complexity of this solution is `O(n)`.

Comment: That works. Do you reckon there's a way to reduce the complexity further?

Comment: I guess, only if you trade time for space (or vice versa).